# RewriteRule working on one subdomain, but not on another?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To set the scene:

- I have 2 versions of a web application I'm working, each running independently on its own subdomain, we'll call them *v1.mydomain.com* and *v2.mydomain.com*.
- I'm using PHP and FPDF to generate PDF's on a website and one of the requirements when you insert images into a PDF using FPDF is that the image filenames must end in *.jpg* or *.png* etc- it identifies the file type from the file name extension, not from a Content-Type header or supplied MIME-type parameter.
- I've written a dynamic PHP script which generates images on-the-fly that I'm inserting into my PDF documents using FPDF. To access the image in a browser I would use a link such as:

  ```
  http://v1.mydomain.com/scaled.php?id=1&w=1024&h=618
  ```

  where required parameters for the image generation are supplied in the query string.
- I'm using an Apache *.htaccess* file to enable me to route a filename ending in .jpg to this script:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^fpdf-scaled-(.*)-(.*)x(.*).jpg$ /scaled.php?id=$1&w=$2&h=$3
  ```

At present this works beautifully on subdomain *v1* but not on *v2*, for which I get an HTTP 404 File Not Found error while trying to locate *fpdf-scaled-1-1024x618.jpg* which tells me the rule hasn't been applied since it's not looking *scaled.php*.

The hosting environment (PHP version, Apache version etc) is exactly the same, they are hosted on the same server, and also the file permissions match exactly between the two sub-domains.

I've been trying to figure this one out for too many hours now and would appreciate some help. If you need any further information let me know. Thank you!

### **Edit 1:**

At present all other lines are commented out so will not be able to affect this issue and should therefore I would think be unhelpful in troubleshooting. For reference though the complete *.htaccess* would be as follows (I'm sure this could be written more efficiently and you're welcome to comment suggestions for this aswell):

```
RewriteEngine on

# GZip compression (*.js)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.js
RewriteRule ^(.*\.)(js)$ gzip.php?file=$1$2 [L]

# GZip compression (*.css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.css
RewriteRule ^(.*\.)(css)$ gzip.php?file=$1$2 [L]

# GZip compression (*.swf)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.swf
RewriteRule ^(.*\.)(swf)$ gzip.php?file=$1$2 [L]

# Exclude publicly accessible static resource folders from friendly URL rewriting
RewriteRule ^(lib|templates) - [L]

# Fpdf URL rewriting for photos
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^fpdf-scaled-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\.jpg$ /scaled.php?id=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [L]

# Friendly URL rewriting
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|gzip\.php|scaled\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

### **Edit 2:**

- Files for sub-domain *v1* are stored in */var/www/v1.mydomain.com/*
- Files for sub-domain *v2* are stored in */var/www/v2.mydomain.com/*
- The server has numerous working virtual hosts, neither of these are the default.

The rewrite log for a request to http://v2.mydomain.com/fpdf-scaled-1-1024-618.jpg (IP addresses omitted and subdomains anonymized):

```
[rid#2ba56a92b108/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /fpdf-scaled-6-1024x618.jpg
[id#2ba56a92b108/initial] (1) pass through /fpdf-scaled-6-1024x618.jpg
[rid#2ba56a92b108/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/v2.mydomain.com/] rewrite 'fpdf-scaled-6-1024x618.jpg' -> '/scaled.php?id=6&w=1024&h=618'
```

Interestingly the same three lines are added to the rewrite log for v1 when it works perfectly to v2 which doesn't work with the only differences being the unique log ID's and the number in the sub-domain.

Comment: Try to be more restrictive in your rule: `RewriteRule ^fpdf-scaled-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\.jpg$ /scaled.php?id=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [L]` (also, like i did, don't forget to escape `.` before `jpg` and don't forget `L` flag after your rule). **Question**: is your url `http://v1.mydomain.com/scaled.php?id=1&w=1024&h=618` also reachable via `http://v2.mydomain.com/scaled.php?id=1&w=1024&h=618` ?

Comment: I've now tried it with your more restrictive regex but it's not solved the issue, behaviour remains the same. While I've isolated this rule as the one that's causing the problem its actually not the last rule that would be applied which is why I've not given it the `[L]` however trying it with that still doesn't solve the issue. Thank you for your suggestions, both the URL's when directly accessed are working fine.

Comment: Please update your question with **entire** htaccess content

Comment: OK I've updated the question now for you Justin

Comment: How are your subdomains set up? Do they each have their own sub-folder, and are those sub-folders on the same level?

Comment: _“I get an HTTP 404 File Not Found error […] which tells me the rule hasn't been applied since it's not looking scaled.php”_ – that might be a wrong conclusion you are drawing here – it might as well be, that the rule _has_ been applied, but the server is not able to find the `scaled.php` script afterwards … depending on how exactly your subdomains are set up (see comment above), I think the leading slash in `/scaled.php?id=$1&…` might(!) probably be to blame.

Comment: This would be much easier to figure out, if you looked into the log files – error log and rewrite log (the latter has to be specifically enabled).

Comment: OK I've updated the question now for you CBroe

Comment: I've now figured out the problem was not related to the different sub-domains but in fact an issue in the PHP script which was resolved when switching to use `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` instead of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` in _scaled.php_. Thank you for your time and suggestions. I'm unfortunately unable to answer or close this question.